# Are questions about community building on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I thought this question had already come up in Area51 but I cannot see it here so I am duplicating it.

Are questions about how to build and manage a programming language community on-topic here or should they be redirected to, for example, [community building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)?

On the one hand programming languages are a unique kind of community on the other so are many other kinds of community.

Answer (score 7):

[Copying my answer from area 51 here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32917/223122)

### No

These questions would be better suited for [community building stack exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I like the caveat to your answer that was added - https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32918/223173

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that caviat but feel free to post another answer with the caviat added

Answer (score 4):

## No

Managing a programming language community is not related to the technical design and implementation. I would not consider these on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself: **who are the experts**?

If the experts are computer scientists or compiler/library implementers, and the community building aspect is not generalizable to other types of communities, ask here.

If the experts are community building experts, don't ask here (but try [Community Building Stack Exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)).

For example, [lessons learned from [a specific aspect of] the C++ community](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/736/what-can-be-learned-from-problems-and-associated-solutions-goals-to-strive-fo) calls from answers from people who are familiar with how the C++ committee works. They are more likely to be language designers and implementers who are not particularly interested in community building in general, than community building experts who don't know about C++. So this is a suitable site.

On the other hand, questions such as inviting open-source participation, maintaining discussion channels, and so on, that could equally apply to many other topics, are off-topic here because this site doesn't have the expertise.